# Selecting implementation (class) depending on variable

Tags: java, python, design-patterns

I got a few classes handling different file extensions. They all got implement a common interface or extend the same abstract class. I want to dynamically (runtime) get the correct subclass depending on the file's extension.

Now I'm a bit stuck where to place the logic to select the correct implementation.
After thinking a bit I would now create a dict inside the parent class doing the selection.
e.g.

```
{"jpg": jpgProcessor,
"gif": gifProcessor}.get(fileExt)().process(file)
```

In Java I would create a register method inside the parentClass which gets invoked by a static block of the children classes. The parentClass would then have a getFilter(String fileExt) method which selects the correct Class out of a HashMap or something similar.

Questions:

- Is there a better way to implement something like this in Python?

bonus:

- Is there a concrete pattern for this? How is it called?
- Is this the correct way to implement this in Java?

I always read many articles about factory, abstract factory patterns but was pretty unsure if i could replace the type checks inside the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Java... In *python*, I might do something like:

```python
class ProcessorSelector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._processor_map = {}

    def register(self, type, processor):
        # type checking goes here if you're worried about it...
        # e.g. `if not isinstance(processor, Processor): raise TypeError`
        self._processor_map[type] = processor

    def select(self, type):
        return self._processor_pam[type]

selector = ProcessorSelector()
selector.register('jpg', JpgProcessor)
cls = selector.select('jpg')
processor = cls()
processor.process(file)
```

Of course, you don't actually *need* the `ProcessorSelector` class at all...  You could just use a regular dictionary :-).

Comment: Could you edit add an **e**  to ´selector = ProcessorSelctor()?´ (missing in Sel**e**ctor)

Comment: @eiselems -- Thanks.  Where would I be without a linter?

Comment: You aren't the only one :D
Would have it edited myself but stackoverflow has a minimum characters limit for edits

Answer (score 4):

In Java, use an `enum`. Lets take your above example with `jpg` and `gif`. Lets assume we have `3` classes:

```java
class Processor {}
class JpgProcessor extends Processor {}
class GifProcessor extends Processor {}
```

We can now use the `enum` factory pattern to create instances:

```java
enum ProcessorFactory implements Supplier<Processor> {
    JPG("jpg", JpgProcessor::new),
    GIF("gif", GifProcessor::new);

    private static final ProcessorFactory[] VALUES = values();
    private final String extension;
    private final Supplier<? extends Processor> supplier;


    private ProcessorFactory(String extension, Supplier<? extends Processor> supplier) {
        this.extension = extension;
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public static ProcessorFactory fromExtension(final String extension) {
        return Arrays.stream(VALUES)
                .filter(v -> v.extension.equals(extension))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid extension " + extension + "."));
    }

    @Override
    public Processor get() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

There are a number of things going on here. First, the `enum implements Supplier<Processor>` which means you can use it to get a `Processor` instance like so:

```java
final Processor jpgProcessor = ProcessorFactory.JPG.get();
```

Next, each `enum` has a `String extension`, these are used to tie a particular `enum` instance to a particular extension. The method `fromExtension` does that, so you can get a the correct value by using:

```java
final ProcessorFactory factory = ProcessorFactory.fromExtension("jpg");
```

So to get a `Processor` from an extension, all you need to do is:

```java
final Processor jpgProcessor = ProcessorFactory.fromExtension("jpg").get();
```

This assumes that you need a `new Processor()` for each interaction. If you do not need that, then a simple `Map<String, Processor>` would work just as well:

```java
final Map<String, Processor> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("jpg", new JpgProcessor());
map.put("gif", new GifProcessor());
```

The to get a processor:

```java
final Processor processor = map.get("jpg");
```

Comment: Was just wondering if you can get around registering all the processors in a central place.Wouldn't it be nice to not have to touch the ProcessorFactory-class when creating a new Processor?

I tried to replace the enum by a HashMap which gets filled by child implementations of Processor. Sadly we would lose the way of invoking a specific Processor like this:
`final Processor jpgProcessor = ProcessorFactory.JPG.get(); `
The problem however is that the registration itself has to be called.

There is no difference in registering or calling registration. Therefore I think this is a great solution.

Comment: @eiselems Indeed, the implementations need to be registered at some point. If you are using a DI framework (Spring, Guice) then they can take care of registration for you, provided the implementations are correctly annotated; but you would still loose the automatic singleton that the `enum` provides. How your project will evolve in the future will dictate which approach works best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method factory pattern. See the example here: 
http://javarevisited.blogspot.se/2011/12/factory-design-pattern-java-example.html
In the example, replace Currency by File and currency symbols by file extensions.

Comment: The class CurrencyFactory does exaclty that what i want to avoid.
If checking all cases.

Comment: @eiselems that example is a little out of date - the `enum` based factory is better I think.

Comment: yes. I'm currently looking at the other (especially @BoristheSpider 's solution). I kind of feel like a idiot not making this question a single language question :(
Now it is hard to select an answer