# Java Select which class to initialize by parameter

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a main **TestConstant** class where the strings for testing are stored.

```
public class TestConstants {
   public static final STRING_TEXT;
}
```

Then, there is a child class **EnglishConstants**. This class will be used if application is using English language:

```
public class EnglishConstants extends TestConstants {
   public static final STRING_TEXT = "Text in English.";
}
```

At the end, there is a child class **PortugueseConstants**. This class will be used if application is using Portuguese language:

```
public class PortugueseConstants extends TestConstants {
   public static final STRING_TEXT = "Text in Portuguese.";
}
```

What's the point:
We want if it is possible, when running the test by Maven build from terminal with "-Dlanguage=" property provided, and based on that property "STRING_TEXT" to be selected in that language.
So, if the:

```
-Dlanguage=pt-pt is provided
```

Test has then to use "TestConstants.STRING_TEXT" and to take the value in the Portuguese language from the "PortugueseConstants" class.

Tried with factory on this question and answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28602106/9074348

Comment: If the constants can be assigned at compile time, you should review Eclipse's Externalized Strings option.  https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fpde_actions%2Fexternalize_strings.htm

Comment: @Reilas Thank you on your answer, but this won't solve our problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all investigation I've decided to ask ChatGPT for the help. So, now we have an proper solution for selecting cross-language constants.
Solution:

```
public class TestConstants {
    public static String STRING_TEXT;
    public static String NEW_TEXT;
    public static String ANOTHER_TEXT;
}
```

```
public class EnglishConstants extends TestConstants {
    static {
        STRING_TEXT = "String Text in English.";
        NEW_TEXT = "New Text in English.";
        ANOTHER_TEXT = "Another Text in English.";
    }
}
```

```
public class PortugueseConstants extends TestConstants {
    static {
        STRING_TEXT = "String Text in Portuguese.";
        NEW_TEXT = "New Text in Portuguese.";
        ANOTHER_TEXT = "Another Text in Portuguese.";
    }
}
```

```
public class ConstantsFactory {
    public static TestConstants getLanguageConstants(String language) {
        switch (language) {
            case "pt-pt":
                return new PortugueseConstants();
            case "en-us":
            default:
                return new EnglishConstants();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Usage example
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String language = System.getProperty("language");
// Initialization of the TestConstant as language by parameter can be stored //in the BaseTest also
        TestConstants languageConstants = ConstantsFactory.getLanguageConstants(language);

        String stringText = languageConstants.STRING_TEXT;
        String newText = languageConstants.NEW_TEXT;
        String anotherText = languageConstants.ANOTHER_TEXT;

        System.out.println("String Text: " + stringText);
        System.out.println("New Text: " + newText);
        System.out.println("Another Text: " + anotherText);
    }
}
```

If you want to run the some test use:

```
mvn clean test -Dlanguage=en-en
```